# Why does this element cause an overflow in a container with the same size?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a div that shows a scrollbar only when the elements don't fit within the default area.

```html
<div style="overflow-y: auto; height: 36px;">
  <img src="." width="36" height="36" />
</div>
```

Unfortunately there is some padding on the bottom of the div, so the scrollbar is always shown even though in theory the img and the div should be the same height. I'm able to reproduce in Firefox and Chrome, so it doesn't seem like a browser bug.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `font-size: 0;` to parent div:

```
<div style="overflow-y: auto; height: 36px; font-size: 0;">
  <img src="." width="36" height="36" />
</div>
```

Comment: Holy crap this worked perfectly! What kind of arcane witchcraft is this?? Seriously though, do you know why this works? PS. just checked and `line-height: 0;` also fixed it for me

Answer (score -1):

Try to get rid of padding in a parent div, or the page all together.

```
<html>
  <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <div style="overflow-y: auto; height: 36px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
      <img src="." width="36" height="36" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work when I try it. http://jsfiddle.net/ucfkv5xp/ I think it's because the doctype is missing in your example, but that's not an option for my project.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to set `float` on `<img>`

```html
<div style="overflow-y: auto; height: 36px;">
  <img src="." width="36" height="36" style="float:left"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I still see overflow in your snippet.

Comment: Though this worked in the snippet for me, it didn't change my issue. Setting font-size to 0 on the parent fixed it though!